# Восcтановить данные из потока ввода

Tags: linux, c

Пользователь вводит информацию в терминале, в это время с другого процесса программы приходит сообщение и затирает данные, которые пользователь уже ввёл, но не отправил.

Как после этого восстановить затертые данные и поместить их на следующую строку за пришедшим сообщением?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LEN 25

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char message[MAX_LEN];
    char answer[MAX_LEN] = "test\n";
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        read(STDIN_FILENO, message, MAX_LEN);        
    }

    if (pid > 0) {
        while (1) {
            sleep(2);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\r", 1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, answer, strlen(answer));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тут нет потоков, fork создает новый *процесс*, переменные у этих процессов в разных адресных пространствах, изменение данных в одном процессе никак не влияет на данные в переменных с тем же именем в другом процессе.

Comment: @avp Это понятно, но тут речь идёт о визуальном отображении данных. Перед тем как write выведет сообщение он возвращает каретку на начало строки и пишет поверх данных, которые начал вводить пользователь но ещё не закончил (не нажал enter). Необходимо данные пользователя перенести на новую строку и сохранить положение курсора, чтобы он смог продолжить ввод.

Comment: Так и опишите это в вопросе. Простым способом ничего тут не сделать. Вам надо специально это запрограммировать, напимер, использовать curses. Т.е. нужно разделить экран на 2 части, вводить в одной (скажем, нижней) а выводить сообщения в другую. Скорее всего тут понадобится еще и синхронизация между процессами. Возможно, лучшим решением будет выделить всю работу с экраном в отдельный процесс с которым взаимодействуют 2 других (например, по пайпам).

Answer (score 3):

Пример где это реализовано: наберите в командной строке `sleep 2` и нажмите Enter, теперь пока команда sleep выполняется наберите что-то, но enter не нажимайте. Когда bash проснётся, он выводит приглашение а потом ваш ввод.
Более простой интерпретатор dash так не умеет. Секрет состоит в отключении режима терминала `ECHO`, который повторяет вводимые символы, включении режима посимвольного ввода и реализации отображения вводимых символов своими силами либо с помощью библиотеки, например GNU Readline.
В режиме посимвольного ввода `read()` будет возвращать результат, когда была нажата хотя бы одна клавиша (правда ещё зависит от размера буфера и параметров VMIN и VTIME, но в любом случае ожидается хотя бы один байт).

Смотрите документацию в [`man tcsetattr`](http://ru.manpages.org/termios/3).

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <poll.h>

...

struct termios t;
tcgetattr(2, &t);
tcflag_t oldtcflags = t.c_lflag;
t.c_lflag &= ~( ECHO | ICANON );
tcsetattr(2, TCSANOW, &t);

// буфер ввода и позиция "курсора" в нём, первый символ - возврат в начало строки
char input[80]="\r", i=1;
// структура для poll, который используем перед read чтобы ждать ввода не более 1 секунды
struct pollfd pollev= {fd:0, events:POLLIN};

// самый тупой редактор тупо заполняет буфер и повторяет его на вывод
while(i<79) {
    char b;
    if(poll(&pollev, 1, 1000)) {
        if(read(0, &b, 1)!=1) break;
        input[i++]= b;
    } // если ничего не введено за одну секунду, всё равно обновим строку, вдруг сообщение испортило экран
    write(2, input, i);
    if(b=='\n') break;
}
input[i]=0;
// Восстановление старого режима терминала
t.c_lflag = oldtcflags;
tcsetattr(2, TCSANOW, &t);
// Далее в буфере input первый символ следует игнорировать

...
```

Данная программа обновляет вводимую строку на экране раз в секунду и каждый раз после ввода очередного символа.

Редактор рассчитан на то что stderr (он же дескриптор 2) связан с тем же терминалом, что и stdin (он же дескриптор 0). Если это не так (пользователь решил перенаправить вывод stderr), он вероятнее всего не увидит наши символы при вводе (если только он не использовал трубу в `tee` или что-то подобное). Т.е. в случае перенаправления stderr мы можем потерять эмуляцию эха. Поэтому я использовал тот же дескриптор для `tcgetattr/tcsetattr`: в случае перенаравления в файл или трубу эти функции не сработают и останется обычный построчный режим с эхом.

В обычной командной строке все три дескриптора на самом деле доступны и на чтение и на запись (возможно в каких-то системах это не так). Полная эмуляция будет, если использовать дескриптор 0 для всех операций в редакторе (`read`, `write`, `poll`, `tcgetattr`, `tcsetattr`), это позволит пользователю перенаправлять вывод как угодно, если же он перенаправит ввод, `write` и управление терминалом не сработают. Вроде бы то, что нужно, но как мне кажется основано на недокументированных возможностях.

Comment: Только `tcgetattr/tcsetattr` надо вызывать с тем же дескриптором (0 -- stdin), с которым вызываете `read` (Вы ведь устанавливаете режимы именно потока ввода), а `write` наверное надо  вызывать с дескриптором 1 (stdout), а дескриптор 2 (stderr) оставить в покое. В текущем виде это работает, поскольку все дескрипторы дапнуты с псевдотерминала эмулятора, а вот с "железным" терминалом (конечно, его сейчас и не найти) `tcgetattr/tcsetattr` с дескриптором 2 (или 1) работать не будет.

Comment: @avp, думаю наоборот, лучше оставить в покое дескриптор 1. Пользователь может перенаправить вывод в файл и редактор будет продолжать нормально работать. Если же он и stderr куда-то перенаправит, то управлять терминалом не нужно, tcsetattr не сработает и будет работать обычный построчный ввод.  Кстати у меня `write` работает даже с дескриптором 0. Почему с железным терминалом не сработает? Попробую зайти на orange-pi по последовательному порту.

Comment: @avp `./a.out > /dev/tty 2>&1` -- так тоже работает.
`./a.out |& tee yyy` -- а вот так не работает, но я сомневаюсь что такое перенаправление нужно.

Comment: Ну, stderr в таком случае тоже может быть перенаправлен. Поэтому tcset/get надо с 0. С /dev/tty естественно работает, это псевдоним того самого псевдотерминала, что связан с эмулятором.

Comment: Кстати, сейчас (без перенаправления) Вы и читать (read) можете хоть с 1, хоть с 2 (а писать (write) в 0) и все будет работать (такая вот путаница!)

Comment: @avp  тогда может быть правильнее всё перевести на один дескриптор 0, но сначала проверить что он доступен на запись.

Comment: Не думаю. Все же традиционно 0 это ввод, 1 и 2 вывод (это привычно и всем понятно). Если оформлять как функцию, так можно просто передать оба дескриптора (для ввода и вывода) в аргументах.

Comment: @avp подключился к последовательному порту orange-pi на котором ubuntu, - всё так же работает

Comment: Интересно. Значит в ней сейчас такой драйвер, что можно весь терминальный ввод-вывод (если исключить перенаправления) вести с дескриптором 0.

Comment: @avp, я имею в виду, что `tcsetattr` работает с портом независимо от того как открыт порт для чтения или для записи или O_RDWR, т.е. меняются свойства порта, - это особенность драйверов. А то что дескрипторы все фактически O_RDWR - это наверно особенность getty или init.