# Добавить текст в строку ввода

Tags: c++

Приветствую. Хочу сделать возможность редактирование переменной, но не нашел функции для добавления текста уже имеющегося значения в строку ввода консоли, для его редактирования. Не подскажете функцию?

P.S Вопрос глупый, но гугл ничего не выдает из-за засилия других глупых вопросов.

Comment: Вы это в консоли хотите сделать?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb да

Comment: Посмотрите на [The GNU Readline Library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) и заодно [GNU History Library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html), с помощью которой можно "листать" вводимые ранее данные (как это делает bash в командной строке)

Comment: Если для linux, можно адаптировать простенький редактор строки из другого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561208/130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот (довольно искусственный) пример использования [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) на Си (также компилируется и g++)
(а вот ссылка на нее для [windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm))

Программа анализирует прочитанную строку и если в ней есть слово, начинающееся с `V:`, то оно подставляется для ввода следующей строки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

static char *ins;

int f() {
  if (ins && ins[0]) {
    rl_insert_text(ins);
    rl_redisplay();
  }
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *line = 0, txt[1000] = "", *p;

  rl_pre_input_hook = f;        // readline() вызовет нашу функцию перед чтением ввода (после вывода промпта)
  rl_bind_key('\t', rl_insert); // для вставки символа табуляции (иначе он работает как поиск дополнения имени файла)
  ins = txt;

  while (line = readline("> ")) {
    printf("line: %s\n", *line ? line : "");
    txt[0] = 0;
    if (p = strstr(line, "V:")) 
      sscanf(p, "%s", txt);

    if (line[0])
      add_history(line);

    free(line);
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Поскольку вложенные функции не поддерживаются в С++ функцию `f()` (readline hook) и массив `char txt[]` (или указатель на него, как в этом примере) приходится выносить на внешний уровень.

Пример вызова:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ t-readline.c -lreadline
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
> ksdkk
line: ksdkk
> ueru V:444
line: ueru V:444
> V:444 kksk
line: V:444 kksk
> End
```

В строке 5 (третий вызов readline) текст `V:444` в начале области ввода подставлен из предыдущей введенной строки.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку система не указана, отвечаю для Linux. Системный вызов `ioctl` с запросом номер `TIOCSTI` помещает один байт в очередь ввода терминала или последовательного порта. Пример использования:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
...
    for(const char*s="моя строка"; *s; s++) ioctl(0, TIOCSTI, s);
```

[Источник](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html)

В Windows для имитации ввода с клавиатуры можно использовать функцию
[WriteConsoleInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687403(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Для ищу решение для windows, к сожалению

Comment: Ну может быть mingw поможет. Вот пишут http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/5044 должна помочь функция WriteConsoleInput